# Strange data returned from Exchange Web Services SDK. How do I update the CAS SCP data?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, ldap, windows, cas

I'm using the [Exchange Web Services SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877012%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) and am getting strange results after these lines run:

```
ScpUrlGuidString = @"77378F46-2C66-4aa9-A6A6-3E7A48B19596";

ScpPtrGuidString = @"67661d7F-8FC4-4fa7-BFAC-E1D7794C1F68";

configSearcher.Filter =
               "(&(objectClass=serviceConnectionPoint)" +
               "(|(keywords=" + ScpPtrGuidString + ")(keywords=" + ScpUrlGuidString + ")))";
```

It seems that one of my CAS servers is missing, and the other is misconfigured.

**Question**

What administrative commands should I run to edit how the CAS publishes or updates the AD SCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the `AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri` property of the Client Access Servers with the Exchange Management Shell (this is the serviceBindingInformation attribute of the CAS SCP):

```
Get-ClientAccessServer | select Name,AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri
```

Update the property with the [Set-ClientAccessServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125157.aspx) cmdlet if necessary

Comment: I thought this too...Any suggestions if this looks correct?  Any way this would get out of sync?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say, since you haven't posted the output along with what you expected :-)